# Will gaming.stackexchange.com redirect to arqade.com soon?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, domain-name, arqade-migration

Right now, `arqade.com` redirects to `gaming.stackexchange.com`. Will we soon be reversing that? Using a unique TLD would probably go a long way toward convincing newcomers that this site is legit.

Comment: I agree and would prefer that it redirects this way, although it probably won't happen :(

Comment: Probably not. That might muck up the Google page rank for one thing, and there's other sites with the same setup ([Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com/), [Seasoned Advice](http://seasonedadvice.com/)).

Answer (score 9):

I have it [on good authority](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4935535#4935535) that arqade.com will continue to redirect to gaming.stackexchange.com:

> We had a long process in coming to this decision, part of it including actual mechanical nuisances involved with actually changing the domain name. I don't recall all of those, so I'll just stick with the other reason - consistency with the other domain names of SE 2.0 sites, and it is our policy going forwards that it'd only ever be a redirect.

Comment: It would be more consistent if the domain name were arqade.stackexchange.com. I get a bad feeling when I punch in [blah].com and am redirected to something else entirely, domain-wise.

Comment: @johnjon, this isn't the way SE handles redirects, for instance [askdifferent.com](http://askdifferent.com) redirects to http://apple.stackexchange.com - it doesn't seem like they're interested in changing this behavior, from what I understand.

Comment: So it sounds like they're saying that the Big 3 sites, stackoverflow.com , serverfault.com , superuser.com are and will always be uniquely privileged. That is, [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) never redirects to [stackoverflow.stackexchange.com](http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com), and so on, something no other SE-2.0 site does. Very very strange. Break out the conspiracy theories!

Comment: @MichaelRatanapintha I'm guessing that's because those sites aren't 2.0. Also, I'm glad the site is still called Gaming, Arqade isn't that good a name.

Comment: @kotekzot Those sites weren't *initially* 2.0.  Right now, the sites that are "*.stackexchange.com" are collectively referred to "2.0".  However, in terms of the software, SO gets the new core engine changes first (well, meta.SO, then SO) and then the rest of the network (although the amount of time between the two isn't *that* much).